# I can't understand why my application is not writing to a file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a way to save data to the android phone for my app. In the `surfaceOnDestroyed` I have added the following code.

```
try {
    outputStream = getContext().openFileOutput("data.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(current.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println(current + " saved");
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Current is a string variable that I call earlier in my code that I print out here to show what it is when I am writing to the file. Each time I get that the variable is 2.

The data.txt file contains one line with a "0" initially placed in the file because the program reads from the file when the application is started.

When I check the data file after I destroy the object, the 0 is still in the file and has not changed to the 2.

I'm not sure what other information might be needed to solve this issue but I can not figure it out. Help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you check it? Are you sure it's the same file?

Comment: I just used an inputstream to read from the file location then printed out the first line and got a 0, so I am sure that it is the right file.

Comment: You should probably post some more code.

Comment: What you have posted looks ok, the problem seems to be somewhere else.